# figuring out if a network is using a static public ip address

Tags: networking, ip

Is there a way to find out without calling the service provider? Are there native tools built into Mac linux or Windows to enumerate this info?

Comment: only if you have access to the gateway router, so you can see how it is configured. a static ip and a dhcp ip have no difference in the characteristics you could observe except from the position of the device directly on that link.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much access you have to this network. If it is a network on an device such as a PC that you can access, you can see if it has a DHCP server assigning its IP adress, but even then, it still can be reserved in the DHCP server itself. But if it doesn't have acquired an IP address from a DHCP server, then you are certain that it has been assigned a static IP address.